# Infinite sum $S(k) = \lambda + 2^k \lambda^2 + 3^k \lambda^3 + \dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, infinite-product, infinite-groups

I'm trying to find an expression for:

$$S(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^k \lambda^n$$
I have found a recursive expression for this where I first find $S(0)$, then use that to find $S(1)$. Then use those to find $S(2)$ and so on until I get to $S(k)$. For large $k$, I will need a computer for this. I want to know if there is a more efficient method, preferably a closed form solution I can calculate without a computer. Here is how my method works:

$$S(k) = \lambda + 2^k \lambda^2 + 3^k \lambda^3 + \dots$$
$$\frac{S(k)}{\lambda} = 1 + 2^k \lambda + 3^k \lambda^2 + \dots$$

Subtracting the first equation from the second equation we get:

$$S(k) \left(\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda} \right) = (1^k-0^k)\lambda^0 + (2^k-1^k)\lambda^1+\dots$$
$$ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ((n+1)^k-n^k)\lambda^n$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{r=0}^{k-1} {k \choose r}n^r\lambda^n $$
$$ =\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}{k \choose r} \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^r \lambda^n$$
$$ = \sum_{r=0}^{k-1} {k \choose r} S(r)$$

So,
$$S(k) = \frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda} \sum_{r=0}^{k-1} {k \choose r} S(r)$$

We know $S(0) = \frac{1}{1-\lambda}$. Can use this to get $S(1), S(2), \dots$. But is there a better way?

Comment: With $|\lambda|<1$ you get $S(k,\lambda) = \Phi(\lambda,-k,0)$ where $\Phi$ is the [Lerch Transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function)

Comment: This is related to the [*Eulerian polynomials*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number) (see Identities section), which in turn has a nice combinatoric interpretation in terms of descent numbers of permutations.

Comment: This is the [polylogarithm function][1] $\operatorname{Li}_{-k}(\lambda)$.

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm

Comment: This is the polylogarithm of order $-kk. Google may help.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Reading through these. Don't see a way so far in 10 minutes of research to use these to improve on the efficiency of my method.

Comment: At least we have the following more explicit way of writing $S(k)$, which also appears in the wikipedia link above: $$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} i^k x^i = \frac{x \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} A(k,m)x^m}{(1-x)^{k+1}}, \qquad A(k,m)=\sum _{i=0}^{m}(-1)^{i}\binom{k+1}{i}(m+1-i)^k.$$